# Type error in Python program, 'int' object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python

The problem is 'TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable', for my perfect square program, here is the pat where the program goes wrong:

```
tested_number = input('What number do you want to test, maximum is 10000? ')    
y = 0   
sum_of_number = sum(int(y) for y in tested_number)#the sum of all the number in the list, highest is 36 due to 10000 limit
digital_root = sum_of_number[0] + sum_of_number[1]
if digital_root == (2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9):
    print(tested_number, 'is not a perfect square')
    pass
print(tested_number, 'is a perfect square')
```

Comment: It may not completely solve the issue, but list comprehensions need to be in square brackets. e.g. `[y for y in ....]`

Comment: You can't get to the digits of a number through subscripts. Do `digital_root = sum(map(int, str(sum_of_number)))` instead.

Comment: @moarCoffee its a generator the way its written. it doesn't need to be built into a list.

Comment: `sum_of_number` is the sum of some numbers which is an `int`. `sum_of_number[0]` tries to subscript the integer but that doesn't make any sense so you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
for y in tested_number
```

You're trying to iterate through the integer assigned to `tested_number`. You cannot do that. I'm not sure which variable you intended to be a list, but neither `y` or `tested_number` is a list.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your program I get

```
$ python3 b.py
What number do you want to test, maximum is 10000? 456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 4, in <module>
    digital_root = sum_of_number[0] + sum_of_number[1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Showing the full traceback in your question is useful because then we can all see exactly which line has the failure. Looking at your code

```
sum_of_number = sum(int(y) for y in tested_number)#the sum of all the number in the list, highest is 36 due to 10000 limit
```

Its really quite straight forward. `sum_of_number` is an `int` (which is what you'd expect a sum of numbers to be) and `int` can't be subscripted.

Answer (score 0):

## Sum over a range

If you want to sum over the range up to the test number, try this:

```
tested_number = input('What number do you want to test, maximum is 10000? ')    
sum_of_number = sum(y for y in range(tested_number))
print sum_of_number
```

---

```
What number do you want to test, maximum is 10000? 20
190
```